# cx_Freeze won't compile scripts imported with importlib.util

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have some code in an `__init__.py` that loops over a directory and imports all of the python files in that directory.

My file structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── MyModule
│   ├── ModuleScripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── NotImportantModuleScript.py
│   │   ├── Lots.py
│   │   ├── Of.py
│   │   ├── Other.py
│   │   └── Scripts.py
│   └── __init__.py # This is the script that imports all of the modules in ModuleScripts.
├── setup.py # Actually called Compile.py
└── MyProgam.py
```

`Main.py` needs to be able to access `MyModule.Lots` which is added by the `__init__.py` and works fine until I compile it with cx_Freeze

The directory I'm importing all the files from is in the same directory as the `__init__.py` and has its own `__init__.py`. I made this part of the script because I'm too lazy to import all of it manually since all of it is needed and I am constantly adding to this directory.

The code looks something like this:

```
root = str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./ModuleScripts")))

for file in os.listdir(root):
    if file.endswith('.py') and not str(file) in ["__init__.py", "NotImportantModuleScript.py"]:
        filePath = str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file)))
        baseName = str(os.path.basename(file)).rsplit('.', 1)[0]

        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(baseName, filePath)
        source = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(source)
```

Now this works perfectly fine when importing my module in another script but when I try to compile it using cx_Freeze none of these files get compiled.

Here is the `setup.py` for cx_Freeze:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32Gui"

setup(
    name="My Programs Name",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="My Programs Description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("MyProgram.py", base=base)]
)
```

My `setup.py` is actually called `Compile.py` since I already have a `setup.py` in the directory but I'm not sure that affects it at all.

The names like `MyProgram.py` are placeholders and not the actual names of my files.

Note: I'm pretty much brand new to cx_Freeze so this code is pretty much ripped out of a tutorial. I haven't been able to find anything online about this issue so I'm using my last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I just need to add the path my modules folder into `build_exe_options["include_files"]`

It would look something like this:

```
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os"],
    "include_files": ["/MyModule"]
}
```

I also removed these 2 lines:

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32Gui"
```

My `setup.py` file now looks like this:

```
import os, sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os", "MyModule"],
    "include_files": ["./MyModule"]
}

base = None

setup(
    name="My Programs Name",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="My Programs Description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("MyProgram.py", base=base)]
)
```